# Can you have explicit auto layout rules for 3.5" iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone, size, autolayout

I've started to use autolayout on my app and it works on 4", 4.7" and 5.5" screens. The problem is when I try it on a 3.5" screen, it requires everything packed a lot more tightly but I don't want to interfere with the auto layout already set up for the other sizes.

Is there any way to have an explicit layout for 3.5" iPhones? As that would make it so much easier.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or defining the auto layout constraints in code?

Comment: @AlohaSilver Storyboard

Comment: Storyboard won't let you do that. Your best bet is to move those constraints to code. If you'd rather not do that, you can turn those constraints into outlets and update them on code as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add check for the running device's screen factor and then add the auto layout constraint in code. Check out this reference for programmatically using auto layout: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

Use this macro in order to detect if the screen is 3.5 inches

```
#define is35Inch  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)?TRUE:FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try and redo the layout and design it for the 3.5" first and then see how it looks on the bigger sizes. But if that doesn't work, I'll definitely use this!